# Why the same alpha value inside and outside of aes behaves differently in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am probably missing something here, but why does the same alpha value produce different results depending if it is specified inside or outside of aes?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

data <- mtcars
data$cyl <- factor(data$cyl)

# alpha within aes
data$alpha <- 1.0
plot1 <- ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = qsec, color = cyl, alpha = alpha), size = 3) + 
  theme_minimal() 

# alpha outside aes
data$alpha <- NULL
plot2 <- ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = qsec, color = cyl), size = 3, alpha = 1.0) + 
  theme_minimal()

print(plot_grid(plot1, plot2, nrow = 1))
```

In my understanding, the plot1 and plot2 should be similar, but plot1 has clearly lower alpha than 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the scale of `alpha` is on [0, 1], you can see this in the `alpha` help file (`?scales::alpha`). This scale is what is used when you state `alpha = 1.0` outside of `aes()` in your plot2. When you call `alpha = alpha` inside `aes()` you're overwriting that default scale of [0, 1] based on the distribution of what is inside your `alpha` column in `df`. Since you only specified one value in your `alpha` column in `df` (i.e. 1.0), that value is treated as the midpoint.

Here is an alternative example where you can see the scale overwriting in more clarity:

```r
data$alpha <- runif(n = 32)

ggplot(data, aes(x = wt, y = qsec, color = cyl, alpha = alpha)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: New plot]